# How to return a 404 from ASP.NET Core exception middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

My application uses a custom NotFoundException, and I'm using the ASP.NET core exception handler middleware to intercept the exception and return a 404 response.

This is a simplified version of the middleware.

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
      app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder => {
        appBuilder.Run(async context => {
          context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
          var responseContent = new {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = "Not found"
          };
          await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(responseContent);
        });
      });
      ...
  }
```

I expect this code to return a 404 response with the content as JSON, but requests simply error out. If I run a test using HttpClient I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Error while copying content to a stream.'
```

If I change the status code in the middleware to anything other than 404 it seems to work as expected.

```
// changing this line
context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
// to this line will successfully return the result
context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

This 404 code was working until I changed the target framework from netcoreapp3.1 to net5.0. What do I need to change in order to successfully return a 404 with JSON from the exception middleware while targeting net5.0?

Comment: Have you seen [AllowStatusCode404Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandleroptions.allowstatuscode404response?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_ExceptionHandlerOptions_AllowStatusCode404Response)?

Comment: I added services.AddExceptionHandler(options => options.AllowStatusCode404Response = true); and that did not fix it. However your comment did lead me down the trail to finding the actual fix.

Answer (score 7):

The problem seems to step from [this update](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25288) to the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.

Adding this line fixed the response when the site is running live.

```
await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
```

However this line did not fix my test using TestServer, because TestServer [does not yet implement](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11598) CompleteAsync.

Comment: Thanks Nick! This was causing some quirky behaviour with a XMLHttpRequest (and by extension axios). It was only a problem with 404. Other status codes were working fine. I think there is some other 404 handling that happens in the pipeline that corrupts the response stream but does it in a way that is not transparent to debugging tools.